# Julia package developement: restarting the kernel wont compile the module

Tags: package, julia, development-environment

I am trying to learn how to develop packages in Julia. At the moment I have created a package `Example.jl`as follows

```
module Example  

greet() = print("Hello World!") # a simple function

include("functions.jl") # calls another file where I define functions f and g

export greet 
export f
export g

end
```

as well as the `functions.jl` file where I define two functions `f` and `g`:

```
f(x,y) = x^2+y^2
g(x,y) = x+y
```

Finally, I go to the `runtests.jl` file to test the package. All works ok except in the case I restart (for whatever reason) the kernel. Then, my `runtests.jl` will give me errors for

```
using Example
using Test

f(1,1)
g(2,2)
```

The error is that the **functions are not defined**!
But it is fine if I use instead

```
using Example
using Test

Example.f(1,1)
Example.g(2,2)
```

In order `f(1,1)`, `g(2,2)` to work like this I need to go to `Example.jl` and re-compile it. This is weird because I assumed that the `export` function in the module will export the functions and that everytime I call the module it compiles itslef. Obviously this is not the case.

**So my question is how to make the module to compile everytime I call it by** `using Example`?

Comment: I have read your question 3x and cannot find out you need. Are you using unit tests? what errors are you getting? what is the file layout of your project? Perhaps you should look at Revise.jl?

Comment: Well, the error is that after I restart the kerner and after I do `use Example` and `use Test` the function is not-defined. Then I need to go to the src file and compile it. After that it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "restart the kernel"... Are you in a REPL or in a Jupyter notebook?  Anyways, right after you "restart the kernel" and issue `using Example`, could you please check that you're loading the module you want to load? You can do this for example by checking where the source code for `Example` comes from, with the following command: `pathof(Example)`

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "recompile the package"? How do you do it?

Comment: Last question: how do you run the tests? Are you using the package manager? Or manually `include("runtests.jl")`? Or something else? (evaluate the source code for the tests from an IDE maybe?)

Comment: I am in Atom using REPL. I can test the package locally in an environment I set up. I  restart the kernel to see if the package would work when a user first calls it. Therefore, starting a new kernel of Julia, I use `using Example`. This should suffice for me to use the methods and functions of this package, right? Well, it will not, unless I go to the source code and tell Julia explicitly `export f` and `export g` (the two functions of the module). Then only I can use `f(1,1)` or `g(1,1)` explicitly. If I don't do this extra step I can only use them as `Example.f(1,1)` or `Example.g(1,1)`.

Comment: And what does `pathof(Example)` return, right after you issue `using Example`?

Comment: It returns the location of the `Example.jl` file. That is, it returns the location of the `Example.jl` file inside the `src` etc along the reverse chain.